# iOS Swift - Cutting video to multiple parts

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app that uploads a recorded video on a server, but it has to be sent in multiple parts which are encoded to base64.

How can I split/cut a video to multiple parts using swift ?

Comment: `subdataWithRange()`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all convert into `NSData` then divide the that data into different different chunks and then that chunk `encode`using base64 that send to server side.

Now, Following is the sample code for same.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Foundation

extension String {
    var ns: NSString {
        return self as NSString
    }
    var pathExtension: String? {
        return ns.pathExtension
    }
    var lastPathComponent: String? {
        return ns.lastPathComponent
    }
}

// MARK: - Mixed string utils and helpers
extension String {


    /**
     Encode a String to Base64

     :returns:
     */
    func toBase64()->String{

        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        return data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var img:UIImageView!=nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()    
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped()
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
        {
            //            print("Camera Available")
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
         dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        let pathString = videoUrl.relativePath
        print(pathString)

        let videoDataURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        let videoFileURLs = videoDataURL.filePathURL

        let chunkSize : Int = 2*1024*1024 // 2 MB
        do {
            let videoData =  try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoFileURLs!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            var newFileName = pathString!.pathExtension
            let totalSizeOfBase64 : Int = Int(videoData.length)
            for var chunksWritten :Int = 0; chunksWritten * chunkSize < totalSizeOfBase64; chunksWritten++
            {
                let modifiedURLString = NSString(format:" %03lu.MOV", chunksWritten) as String
                newFileName = newFileName!+modifiedURLString

                let rangeValue  = NSMakeRange(chunksWritten * chunkSize, min(chunkSize, totalSizeOfBase64 - chunksWritten * chunkSize))
                let finalString  = videoData.subdataWithRange(rangeValue)

                //Encoding Base64
                let base64String = finalString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

                print("\(base64String)")
//                print("\(newFileName)")
                newFileName = pathString!.pathExtension
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

May this helps lot.

Comment: 2MB = 2 * 1024 * 1024